# How to insert column cells from listbox using userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a background in PHP and .Net but I am new to VBA. Is it possible to add specific column cells in excel coming from listbox in userform? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is very much possible.

Comment: @Harun24HR Can you give me idea? First, I put it in array the items in listbox. I can also call all arrays in "msgbox" but I cant insert it in column cells. Do I need to use Range function and get the last column then loop it to insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already manage to insert a new column coming from userform. This is my code.

```
Private Sub btnSaveParameters_Click()

    Dim totalParameters As Integer
    totalParameters = ListBox1.ListCount

    Dim lColumn As Long
    Dim addlColumn As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Reference")
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Do Until i >= Me.ListBox1.ListCount
        MsgBox "The vaue of i is: " & ListBox1.List(i)
        lColumn = ws.Cells(3, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        addlColumn = lColumn + 1
        ws.Cells(3, addlColumn).Value = Me.ListBox1.List(i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```